# Shared Video Uri leads to "No content provider" after App restart

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-fileprovider

My activity gets the Uri of a shared video and saves it to the database:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("video")){
        Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        Log.i("MyActivity", uri.toString());
        // save uri.toString() to database
        // ...
    }
}
```

If the video is shared with Android's File Explorer Log.i prints

```
content://media/external/video/media/8719
```

whereas if the video is shared with MxPlayer the Log.i prints

```
content://com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro.fileprovider/external_storage_root/Movies/20201026_192614.mp4
```

After restarting the App it's only possible to play the video with the first Uri. Using the latter Uri leads to

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: content://com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro.fileprovider/external_storage_root/Movies/20201026_192614.mp4
```

How do I handle Uris from thirdparty Apps? Is it possible to convert the shared Uri to a "generic" format? Is it a permission issue?

Comment: But can you play it at receiving the uri?

Comment: yes, the video is played

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a `Uri`, you have very limited time to use it. And for a `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_SEND`, you should assume that:

- Your activity that responds to the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` can use the `Uri`
- You cannot persist the `Uri` and use it in the future

> How do I handle Uris from thirdparty Apps?

For `ACTION_SEND`, use it immediately. Do not attempt to save it to a database. For a `Uri` that you get via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, [you have more options](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

> Is it possible to convert the shared Uri to a "generic" format?

No, sorry.

Comment: thank you for the clarification about the lifecycle of the `ACTION_SEND` intent. I'm still curious though why the first Uri still works after reading it from the storage. Is it because of the more formal format of the Uri?

Comment: @paddel10: No, in part because there is no concept of "formal format". The first one happens to be a `Uri` from `MediaStore`. You may have rights to access that content beyond the rights granted to you via the `ACTION_SEND` flow. Think of the first `Uri` as being like a URL to a publicly-visible Web page. Think of the second `Uri` as being like a URL to a password-protected Web page, where *at the time* the user happens to be logged in and has an active session. Eventually that session times out. While the session is good, you can use the URL, but not afterwards.